# How to return value from a function into a thread in python using queue and threading classes

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I'm new to threading and queue. So, I wrote this program where I'm trying to return a value to one of the 2 functions in the threading class MyThread and print/process the returned value in the main() function :

```
import threading
import datetime
import Queue

a=Queue.Queue()
b=Queue.Queue()
q=Queue.Queue()

class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,q):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.que=q
        t1=threading.Thread(target=self.prints,args=(4,))
        t2=threading.Thread(target=self.printy,args=(6,self.que,))
        t1.start()
        t2.start()
        item=self.que.get()
        print(item)
        print "*"*30
        it=item*2
        print(it)
        t1.join()
        t2.join()

    def main(self):
        t3=threading.Thread(target=self.prints,args=(3,))
        t4=threading.Thread(target=self.printy,args=(5,self.que,))
        t3.start()
        t4.start()
        item=self.que.get()
        print(item)
        print "#"*30
        it=item*2
        print(it)
        t3.join()
        t4.join()

    def prints(self,i):
        while(i>0):
            print "i="+str(i)+" "+str(datetime.datetime.now().time())+"\n"
            i=i-1

    def printy(self,i,b):
        r=0
        while(i<10):
            print "i="+str(i)+" "+str(datetime.datetime.now().time())+"\n"
            i=i+1
            r=r+i
        self.que.put(r)

if __name__=='__main__':
    MyThread(a).main()
```

However, even though I manage to get the output as I want. I'm curious to know that how the same can be achieved if my function printy() is modified as below:

```
def printy(self,i,b):
    r=0
    while(i<10):
        print "i="+str(i)+" "+str(datetime.datetime.now().time())+"\n"
        i=i+1
        r=r+i
    return(r)
```

How could queue be used to get the returned values? Or do we have any alternate way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You only ever put items in the queue but never get them out. At the end of `__init__`, however, you join the queue, which blocks until the queue has been consumed. Since up until that point, no consumer has been launched, it will block forever.

## Update

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve: now your program will terminate with the queue still active in the background; in both `__init__` and `main`, you put in 4 items but get out only one. If that really produces the output you want, I'm not sure what to suggest.

On the other hand, assuming that you're trying to implement a producer-consumer system, you could something like this:

```
import Queue
import threading

class ProduceConsume(object):

    def produce(self, n):
        for i in xrange(n):
            print 'producing {}'.format(i)
            self.queue.put(i)

    def consume(self):
        while self.running:
            try:
                i = self.queue.get(timeout=0.1)
            except Queue.Empty:
                continue
            print 'consuming {}'.format(i)
            self.queue.task_done()

    def main(self, n):
        self.queue = Queue.Queue()
        self.running = True
        consumer = threading.Thread(target=self.consume)
        consumer.start()
        producer = threading.Thread(target=self.produce, args=(n,))
        producer.start()
        producer.join()
        self.queue.join()
        self.running = False
        consumer.join()

ProduceConsume().main(4)
```

Now, if you want to obtain a kind of result value from the producer thread (the one that puts items in the queue like your `printy`, you cannot simply return it since the return value of a thread's execution target isn't used. You could store it somewhere (maybe as an attribute on your `ProduceConsume` instance) and access it after the producer thread has been joined. Since you ask how to use the queue for it, however, you'd need to put it in the queue as the last item and handle it appropriately in the consumer thread:

```
def produce(self, n):
    r = 0
    for i in xrange(n):
        print 'producing {}'.format(i)
        self.queue.put(i)
        r += i
    self.queue.put(r)

def consume(self):
    while self.running:
        try:
            i = self.queue.get(timeout=0.1)
        except Queue.Empty:
            continue
        print 'consuming {}'.format(i)
        self.queue.task_done()
    else:
        print 'result was: {}'.format(i)
```

To further avoid treating the result as just another item before finding that it was the last item gotten from the queue, you'll need more complex items, such as `('item', i)` and `('result', r)` that tell you whether they represent a regular item or the result.

Comment: Have modified my post to reflect your edits/suggestions and have emphasized on the actual problem. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: In my case, the threads are only producer functions that return a value to the main function. No exchange of values among the threads. So, I need to give `self.queue.task_done()` in the main function after I print/process the value I obtain from the queue?

Comment: Yes, wherever you `get` a value from the queue, you need to call `task_done` as well. On the other hand, you still need some loop for getting values out of the queue if you want the queue to be empty in the end.

Comment: So, every `get` pops/removes the latest value from the queue? Isn't that like how a stack works?

Comment: Every `get` takes the first value from the queue, it's how a queue works ;-) I'm not sure what makes you think of LIFO behaviour. The `task_done` call just decrements a scalar counter of open tasks, which in turn gets incremented by `get`. Nothing to do with the order of consumption.

Comment: Ohhh okay. So, the recommended way is to use queue but use `task_done()` immediately after `get` to avoid the program from terminating while the queue is active? And then, can we use the same queue again to get values from some other producer function using `get` as well?